# Unity Does Not Load Some Of The Modeling Objects

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, 3dsmax, 3ds

I'm working on a project in Unity 5 and I'm facing a weird problem! My problem is that some of the 3Ds Max files does not load in Unity. I mean I can't insert them into the scene and I don't know why!

Here is the print screen:

[image: print screen]

As you can see I have 3 models here but none of them can be inserted into the scene somehow... So do you know how to solve this problem ? thx

Comment: Drag it to the hierarchy instead of the scene and see what happens

Comment: The forbidden icon appears as same as the scene

Comment: Is 3Ds Max installed on your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the .max files directly, but there can be more caveats than you think. According to the official forum there are some requirements to .max files:

- A licensed copy of that software must be installed on all machines
  using the Unity project
- Files can become bloated with unnecessary data
- Big files can slow Unity updates
- Less validation, so it is harder to troubleshoot problems

The latter one really concerns me. Try to export your models as .FBX - maybe you even could see errors and warnings while exporting.

Also check again these documentation links:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectMax.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Mesh.html